# how do I create a qliksense app with multiple paramaterised instances

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I'm brand new to qlik.  I've been handed over a very complicated application with a lot of business logic that is constantly changing that can run against three different databases - ie dev/test/prod.    Basically to decide *which* one it runs against, the developers have been opening the app and changing a variable at the top to basically point to which environment it should run against - and then running it.

To me - there's nothing about having to change the code each time I want to run that's ok.   I know I could duplicate the app for each environment - but that's even worse, because then there are three places to maintain logic when it changes.

**what i want** is to have three instances that somehow share code - for instance - create three apps - "run_dev", "run_test", "run_prod" that just set a variable and then call the fourth app which is the actual code...

But I have no idea how to do it.    What's the best practice way of having a single app with different "modes" of operation - surely people don't always change the code every time they run?

Answer (score 1):

Probably is better to have the variable in external script. So when you want to change the environment just edit the external script and reload the app.

Loading external scripts is done through [Include/Must_include](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2021/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/SystemVariables/Include.htm). The external script is just a text file with Qlik load script (so you can edit the file with any text editor)

(The difference between `Include` and `Must_include` is that `Must_include` will throw an error if the external script is not found)

Example:

```
// External script - environmentSetup.qvs

set vDataConnectionName = DEV;
```

```
// Actual app that loads the data (pseudo script) (Qlik Sense)
$(Must_Include=lib://Folder-Connection-To-Script-Location/environmentSetup.qvs);

LIB CONNECT TO '$(vDataConnectionName)';

Load *;
SQL 
SELECT * FROM `Some_Table`;
;
```

Another possible option is to use [Binary](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/February2021/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptRegularStatements/Binary.htm) load. This type of load is loading data from other qvf/qvw files. It basically opens the target file and loads all the data from it. Once loaded the whole data model is available.